# KSQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP function is not dinamic on streams created with queries

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm creating the following stream:

```sql
CREATE STREAM riderLocations (profileId VARCHAR, latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE, publishtime VARCHAR) 
WITH (kafka_topic='locations', value_format='json', partitions=1);
```

and then this other one:

```sql
CREATE STREAM INVENTORY WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='locations_in') 
AS select * FROM riderLocations 
where STRINGTOTIMESTAMP(publishtime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ') < UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

when I execute the command: `select * from inventory emit changes;`

it only presents the messages that had a publish date smaller than the moment when the inventory stream was created.

How can I force the unix_timestamp value to update and update my stream inventory?

Comment: What version of ksqlDB are you using?

Comment: I was just digging around and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` should be a function call and thus be re-evaluated for each input record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp is evaluated at query creation time, not runtime.

If you actively want messages less than "now", you'll need to include that as a WHERE clause for each SELECT query you run